# Can't get textilate.js to work outside default settings

Tags: jquery, text, jquery-animate

I am trying to use textilate.js to animate some text. When I use the most basic function

```
$("#ttl1").textillate();
```

the effect works ok.

However when I try to apply a different one,, like the one below... nothing happens. No effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $("#ttl1").textillate({ 

        initialDelay: 0,
        autoStart: true,

    in: {
        effect: 'flash',
        delayScale: 1.5,
        delay: 50,
        sync: false,
        shuffle: true
        },

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you including the Textillate, Lettering and Animate libraries? Based on the issue you're having I can assume you're linking to *raw.github.com*, which will cause this issue.

The problem is that *raw.github.com* serves content as `text/plain` and uses the `nosniff` Content-type option. This is done to prevent raw.github.com from being used as a CDN (since it was never designed to be a CDN). You'll need to either host the files yourself or link to a different URL for the animations to work.

It's worth noting that most browsers will still load and execute the JavaScript (at least in my experience), but not the CSS. Since it's the Animate CSS library that provides the animation effects, this is why your example isn't working.

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Unvj4/3/) Your options are fine, but if the CSS doesn't load then none of the effects will work.

*Side Note: When you're having problems,  it's always worth trying out your site in multiple browsers with the developer/debug console enabled. In almost all cases, at least one of the browsers will give you a hint as to what's going wrong in the console.*

Comment: I am not including raw.github. Libraries are hosted on site location. I am including lettering and animate libraries before textilate. Calling the code above in a js file after included libraries.

Comment: Are you sure all of the JS and CSS libraries are being loaded and served with the correct Content-Type? Load up your site in Chrome with the dev console enabled and see if you have any errors.

Comment: I will go re-check everything and get back to you.

Comment: You definitely got me on the right path. I am doing this as part of a drupal installation and the animate.css was not getting picked up. Thank you for the help and the effort with fiddle. I appreciate it very much.